# Dynamically setting Hyperlinks in GridView from code behind

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I was looking for a way to set the url of a HyperlinkField from the code behind but I couldn't find what I needed so I was able to find a solution by modifying code that I use to add required field validators to a column.

Instead of using an TemplateField or HyperlinkField I am just using a standard BoundField then adding a hyperlink to it as part of the RowDataBound event.

HTML

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
```

Code behind RowDataBound event

```
Dim HyperLink As New HyperLink With {
                .Text = e.Row.Cells(0).Text.ToString(),
                .NavigateUrl = "view_item.aspx?id=" + e.Row.Cells(0).Text.ToString()
                }
            e.Row.Cells(0).Controls.Add(HyperLink)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is in the question, hope this helps somebody.